# Variadic kinds in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want my function `memoize(fn)` to return another function with the same type as `fn`.

I have an ugly solution like the following:
Whats the right way to write variadic generics?

```
export const memoize = <FN>(fn: FN) : FN => {
  const cache = { };
  const run : any = (...args) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);
    if(!cache[key]) {
      cache[key] = (fn as any)(...args).catch(up => {
        delete cache[key];
        throw up;
      });
    }
    return cache[key];
  };
  return run as FN;
}

const get = memoize((url: string) => fetch(url, {method: 'GET'}));
```

Comment: I don't think you could get better than this. And what's wrong with it? you're basically defining a function that takes any function and returns a function of the same type back. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @toskv But i don't have access to parameter types of the function.
Is there something like `<...ARGS, R>(fn: (...ARGS) => R) => {` ?

Comment: as far as I know there's no way to get the type of the arguments of a random function you receive as a parameter. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no support for [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) in Type Script.  Luckily, you probably don't need it.

There are two sides to a function: the "outside", which is the signature that callers use, and the "inside", which is the implementation.  Ideally, you want the signature to restrict outside callers to exactly the safe usages of the function, while at the same time you want TypeScript to ensure that your inside implementation of the function is also safe.  Let's first look at the outside:

It looks like you want `memoize` to take a function of any number of any type of parameters which returns a Promise (right?), and you want it to return the same type of function.  Your existing signature `<FN>(fn: FN) : FN` gets the "return the same type" part, but doesn't do anything else.  So, for example, nothing stops callers from doing this:

```
const bad = memoize((x: string)=>x+"!"); // runtime explosion, no .catch()
const veryBad = memoize("whoops"); // runtime explosion, not a function
```

Here's a signature that only allows the right kind of function to be entered:

```
export const memoize = <FN extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<{}>>(fn: FN): FN => { 
  // ... same implementation 
}
```

Now callers will be happy:

```
const get = memoize((url: string) => fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })); // okay
const getBody = memoize((url: string, body: any) => fetch(url, { method: 'GET', body: body })); // okay
const bad = memoize((x: string) => (x + "!")); // error: string is not a Promise
const veryBad = memoize("whoops"); // error: "whoops" is not a function
```

---

This leaves the inside: implementation safety.  Right now, you are relying on asserting to and from `any` (with some implicit `any` in there).  Now that TypeScript knows that `fn` returns a `Promise`, you can relax some of those assertions:

```
export const memoize = <FN extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<{}>>(fn: FN): FN => {
  const cache: { [k: string]: Promise<{}> } = {}; // holds promises
  const run = (...args: any[]) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);
    if (!cache[key]) {
      // fn doesn't have to be any to typecheck
      cache[key] = fn(...args).catch(up => { 
        delete cache[key];
        throw up;
      });
    }
    return cache[key];
  };
  return run as FN;
}
```

You still need to assert that `run` is type `FN`, because all TypeScript knows is that `FN` is a subtype of the type of `run`, not that it *is* the type of `run`.  There is a good reason for this: you could pass in a function with an extra property, and you are making the unwarranted assertion that you will return the extra property also:

```
const crazyFunction = Object.assign((url: string) => fetch(url, { method: 'GET' }), { color: 'purple' });
crazyFunction('blah');
console.log(typeof crazyFunction.color); // string
const whoops = memoize(crazyFunction);
console.log(typeof whoops.color); //TS says string, but is undefined!!
```

I'm going to guess that you don't care what happens to someone who starts doing weird things to their functions before calling `memoize`; especially since that person would probably be you and you know you won't do that.  So this might be good enough for you.

---

If you really wanted to make the implementation and the call signature truly safe, you might find you need variadic kinds, which we don't have in TypeScript.  You can fake it up by accepting functions of up to some large but finite number of arguments, say 9:

```
type Func<R, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9> = (a1: A1, a2?: A2, a3?: A3, a4?: A4, a5?: A5, a6?: A6, a7?: A7, a8?: A8, a9?: A9) => R;
export const memoize = <R, A1=never, A2=never, A3=never, A4=never, A5=never, A6=never, A7=never, A8=never, A9=never>(fn: Func<Promise<R>, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9>): Func<Promise<R>, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9> => {
  const cache: { [k: string]: Promise<R> } = {};
  const run : Func<Promise<R>, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9> = (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9]);
    if (!cache[key]) {
      cache[key] = fn(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9).catch(up => {
        delete cache[key];
        throw up;
      });
    }
    return cache[key];
  };
  return run;
}
const get = memoize((url: string) => fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })); // okay
get('hello') // okay
get('hello', 2); // error, 2 is not assignable to undefined
```

But that might be overkill for you.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this properly.

```js
export const memoize = <T, U extends unknown[]>(fn: (...args: U) => Promise<T>) : (...args: U) => Promise<T> => {
  const cache: {[index:string]: Promise<T>} = {};
  const run = (...args: U) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);
    if(!cache[key]) {
      cache[key] = fn(...args).catch(up => {
        delete cache[key];
        throw up;
      });
    }
    return cache[key];
  };
  return run;
}
```